# What is a real word that means "disenthused"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to get across the point that I was no longer enthusiastic about something:

> When I walked in the room I was disenthused by what I saw.

[AFAIK](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/enthuse/antonyms), *disenthused* isn't a word.

---

Edit: [Chasly](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/270643/123046) was right about my question being more vague than I intended.  Lots of great answers which can only be discriminated by criteria I failed to include in the original post.  I will not repeat the mistake for future postings.

Thank you all for the help.  I've marked the answer that best fits my situation as "accepted", but future Googlers should scroll through the list of answers for their needs.

Comment: Look up synonyms for apathetic, disappointed, uninterested or not excited.

Comment: I saw this question and thought 'apathetic' too

Comment: One (perhaps unexpected) option in the example you give is _sobered_, not in the sense of "sobered up" (that is, no longer drunk) but in the sense of "suddenly aware of the true dimensions and seriousness of the situation or challenge."

Comment: "*unenthusiastic about* what I saw" ?

Comment: In my opinion, disenthused is a perfectly legitimate word. In fact, I rather like it.

Comment: @goblin I like it too; the connotation my mind has is that it means going from enthused to unenthused due to the usage of 'dis-' in some situations as in indication of losing state. While not true for all instances of 'dis-', in this case it works well as a transitional form for enthused and unenthused.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may use [dispirit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dispirit):

> - Cause (someone) to lose enthusiasm or hope: (ODO)
>
>   - *the army was dispirited by the uncomfortable winter conditions*

or  [disappoint](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disappoint):

> - fail to satisfy the hope, desire, or expectation of. (AHD)

- I was dispirited / disappointed by what I saw.

Comment: With a similar connotation than "dispirited": desperate

Comment: *Dispirit* fits my specific scenario best, but *disappoint*, *disenchant* and other top suggestions will certainly help future viewers.

Answer (score 27):

*Unenthused* is a real word, at least in British English.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unenthused

Comment: Example: "When I walked into the room and saw such-and-so, I felt distinctly unenthused."

Comment: Just a data point, but I'm an American and I also use unenthused on occasion and have never had anyone look at me funny. However, I do talk a little differently than the normal person, so it's probably not all that common in the vernacular.

Answer (score 19):

You may consider **disenchanted**, even if *disappointed* is a better fit for your sentence.

> Definition: *no longer happy or satisfied with something. If you are disenchanted with something, you are disappointed with it and no longer believe that it is good or worthwhile (synonyms: disappointed, dissatisfied).*

EDIT - *definition from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disenchanted) and [Reverso dictionnary](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/disenchanted)*.

Comment: This is the best answer: a push down from +1 to 0. The alternatives so far suggested mean (or usually mean) from somewhere above 0 to -1.

Comment: If that definition is not one of your own making, please supply a reference and a link for where you copypasta'd it from.

Answer (score 19):

A possible word is ***dishearten***:

> : to cause (a person or group of people) to lose hope, enthusiasm, or courage : to discourage (someone)
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dishearten)</sub>

(The definition makes it a synonym of Josh61's *dispirit*.)

> When I walked in the room I was *disheartened* by what I saw.

Answer (score 10):

I think the word *underwhelmed* would suit your sentence. From the [Macmillan Dictionary entry:](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/underwhelmed)

> Not at all impressed or excited. Not feeling excited or enthusiastic. Bored, restless, apathetic.

When I walked into the room, I was *underwhelmed* by what I saw.

Answer (score 3):

Really you haven't given us enough information to be certain. That is why you are gathering guesses. Here's mine:

When I walked in the room I was **demotivated** by what I saw.

> demotivate
>
> to make someone less ​enthusiastic about a ​job:
>
> She was very demotivated by being told she had little ​chance of being
>   ​promoted.
>
> [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/demotivate)

Answer (score 3):

Possibly, *jaded*?

> feeling or showing a lack of interest and excitement caused by having done or experienced too much of something

http://i.word.com/idictionary/jaded

Comment: that sounds like something that you did made you "disenthused"  which is not the case of the OP, something about the room made them "disenthused"

Answer (score 3):

I like some of the suggestions made by the others. Additionally:-

1. Deflated (in spirit)- this is idiomatic but somewhat casual
2. Disillusioned - this is stronger

Answer (score 1):

A good word that indicates reduction of enthusiasm is *discouraged*.

Comment: encouraged and enthusiastic are two very different words, so their negatives would also be very different in meaning.

Comment: +1 to negate what I consider an unreasonable downvote. In my opinion, _discouraged_ is a perfectly good suggestion as a fill-in-the-blank word in the questioner's example sentence. This particular answer would be stronger if you included the relevant dictionary definition of the term, but it's not a worthless answer in any case. Merriam-Webster, for example, equates one sense of _discourage_ with _dishearten_, and one of the other answers to this question has received 15 upvotes for suggesting _disheartened_ as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

*Nonplussed* can work as well. As defined in [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/nonplussed):

> (Of a person) surprised and confused so much that they are unsure how
>   to react.

Comment: Please note: [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/nonplussed) is ***not*** the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com)!

Answer (score 1):

When I walked into the room I felt **turned off** by what I saw.

```
 Turn off:

 a. To affect with dislike, displeasure, or revulsion: That song really turns me off.

 b. To affect with boredom: The play turned the audience off.

 c. To lose or cause to lose interest; withdraw: turning off to materialism.

 d. To cease paying attention to: The student turned off the boring lecture and daydreamed.
```

(American Heritage)